# MySQL single insert using subquery rows as columns

Tags: php, mysql

How would I select 3 question IDs and use them as column data in for a single insert statement, using only MySQL.

I currently use the following statement to insert a new row into the game table by selecting a single random entry from the question table:

**Current Table:**

```
 -------------------------------
| game | user_id | question_id |
 -------------------------------
| 1    | 1       | 10          |
```

**Current Statement:**

```
INSERT INTO game (user_id, question_id)
 SELECT u.id as user_id, q.id as question_id
 FROM user u, question q
 WHERE u.id =:uid
 AND q.category = :category
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 1
```

**Game table:**
I have added the columns opt_1-3 to allow for multiple choice

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
| game | user_id | question_id | opt_1 | opt_2 | opt_3 |
 -------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | 1       | 10          | 5     | 12    | 80    |
                                 ^       ^       ^
                               alternative wrong answers
```

*I can achieve this with PHP, iterating over results and using two queries.*

```
SELECT id FROM question
WHERE category = :category
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3

$opts = array();
foreach($result as $r){
    $opts[] = $r->id;
}

INSERT INTO game (user_id, question_id)
 SELECT u.id as user_id, q.id as question_id, 
 // add the following line to the query posted previously
 $opt[0] AS opt_1,  $opt[1] AS opt_2,  $opt[2] AS opt_3
 ...
```

I want to know if its possible to achieve the same result purely using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested this much but this might do the job as the select for you.

Note that an order by rand() is not quick, and this involves a couple of cross joins which will also likely be slow if there are a large number of questions.

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, Sub1.aid, Sub1.bid, Sub1.cid
FROM user u, 
(SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, c.id AS cid
FROM question a, question b, question c
WHERE a.category = :category
AND a.category = :category
AND a.category = :category
AND a.id != b.id
AND a.id != c.id
AND b.id != c.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1) Sub1
WHERE u.id =:uid
```

Comment: That worked! I've been experimenting with statements just like this all day, but I couldn't quite get my head round it, and never working as expected. (even started to look at pivots! :/) I have read up a little on RAND() being slow and how to optimize it, but while I'm building and testing it will suffice for now. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help. Things like this make me think a bit.